# Are there any Power-Ups or plugins that support automatically formatting bulleted lists in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-powerup

I know Trello supports bulleted lists through markdown language, but I would like to have bulleted lists created similar to how Google Docs or Microsoft Word does it.

Are there any solutions out there to automatically format bulleted lists in Trello? Specifically in the description section on the card?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try "Notes & Docs" Power ups.

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).